# Sharing a file between multiple virtualhosts

Tags: php

I have a couple domains (each one has its own virtual host) that use and I have a list of users I block from the domains by IP This is how I currently check the list for an IP on every single virtual host :

```
file("../checkip.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
```

Instead of uploading the same exact file to every single domain I have, is it possible for me to use something like :

```
file("http://maindomain.com/checkip.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
```

That way I can continue to update only one file and use that unique file across multiple domains, or does the file have to be on the same domain?

If the way I'm trying to do this doesn't work, is there anything else I can do to pull the IP Addresses from one file in one location?

Comment: @AndréDaniel so what would be the best solution to have multiple domains check 1 file?

Comment: @AndréDaniel multiple domains on the same server, but yes

Comment: why not using a database?

Comment: @AndréDaniel multiple domains on the same hosting/server setup.

Comment: if you MUST use a file then why not creating symlinks for that one file on every domain?

Comment: @ITroubs i dont know how to create symlinks, is this the only way?

Comment: If it's the same server, you create one file somewhere like in `/var` and then make symlinks to it from each domain's virtual host directory, so that each domain will appear to have its own `checkip.txt` file while in reality it'll be the same `/var/checkip.txt` file.

Comment: There is never only one way in IT, but this is the correct way. Accessing resources on the same server via HTTP is plain stupid and unnecessarily consumes resources.

Comment: @JoeBobby in computerscience there is almost never something like "the ohnly way"

Comment: @AndréDaniel also checking a file for a certain ip address is also unnecessarily consuming resources compared to using any kind of database that is specially made for stuff like that

Comment: @ITroubs I'm not so sure... reading a file on each request could actually be faster than hitting the DB each time... it really depends on what the author wants to do, if it's only on a single, specific page then it's okay, if this code is called on each page and he wants to ban users from his entire website then he may as well just use IPtables to deny the connections.

Comment: @AndréDaniel it all depends on the number of ip's in the file

Comment: @ITroubs even for insane amounts of IPs, IPtables (using an IPSet) is always more efficient than any file or DB.

Comment: I am not arguing about ITrables ;-)

Comment: Another solution would be to use an in-memory database like Redis or Memcached. But really, if you want to ban users from the entire site, the right way to do it is at the firewall level.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you could create a single file somewhere containing the list of IPs, and then make symlinks to it in each virtual host's folder.

If you don't enforce PHP's `open_basedir` directive per each virtual host (you should), you can just create a single file somewhere, give the user the web server runs as permission to read that file, and use an absolute path to that file in `file()` when opening it.

Now, let's talk about what you're trying to achieve; you want to ban users from your site.

If you have root access to your server, and it hosts only one website (or you want to ban users from all websites hosted by that server), you should use IPtables and an IPset if you have a large quantity of IPs to ban, that would be more efficient since the packets won't even reach your web server.

Now, if you don't have root access or you need a per-virtualhost banlist, you should use your web server's configuration (or an `.htaccess` file), I'm assuming you use Apache so check [their documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) for info about how to deny access to hosts; as always it's still way more efficient than doing it with PHP.

Comment: Crap answer (just a recap of my comments) to crap/unclear question but I'm leaving this here just so the question doesn't stay "unanswered".